# Apple Mach-O Linker Error GoogleAnalyticslib

Tags: ios

Hi I cant compile my app because of Apple Mach-O linker error, last time it worked when i removed the architecture arm64, but I need another solution to make it work. Please watch these pictures with the errors I'm getting.[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not including the Google Analytics library.

In Xcode select target.

In the general tab, scroll down until the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" .

Do you have libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a in the list ?
If not, this is your problem.

If you already have them, then the library might not contain the x64 symbols.

Download the latest library from google (they added support for x64 in January).

As a side note, x86_64 , the target you are compiling for, seems to be a simulator. arm64 and x86_64 are different platforms.

Comment: I already had it in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" but it wasn't the latest version thanks.

Comment: I also had to link the slqlite3 lib in "Frameworks and libraries"